# Full width banner needs to be centered when over 1400px

Tags: css, scale

Short version of my question: 
get image horizontal centered when > 1400px and not align at top (see fiddle)

On my site I have an image which is 1400x450px and always touches the sides (full width). When I smallen my browser < 1400px its always centered into that div and keeps being 1400x450. When the browser is larger as 1400px the image needs to be scaled to full width. This all works.

But now my problem:
When my browser is larger as 1400px the image needs to be centered horizontal into the div which can't be higher as 500px. So when the height of the image gets larger as 520px then it needs to scale into the div and keep being **centered horizontal** (overflow hidden).

This all works but its not being centered when the image gets heigher as 520px.

If you see my example it will be a bit clearer what I mean. (and have a large screen)

Full screen:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/fourroses666/hs8hr0vd/show/

The HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/1400x450" /></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.banner{overflow:hidden; position:relative; height:450px;}
.banner img{min-width:100%; width:1400px; margin-left:-700px; display:block;}
.banner .image{position:absolute; width:100%; left:50%; height:450px; margin:0 auto;}

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) { 
    .banner{overflow:hidden; height:auto; max-height:520px; position:relative; margin:0; left:auto; width:100%;}
    .banner img{margin:0; display:block;}
    .banner .image{height:auto; left:auto; position:relative;}
}
```

### EDIT

My version with background image:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.banner .image{overflow:hidden; position:relative; background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1400x450); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; background-size: 100% auto; height:450px;}
.banner{display:block; height:450px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) { 
    .banner .image{background-size: 1400px 450px;}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to center it in the vertical or the horizontal?

Comment: the top and bottom may be cropped, the width is always full. I'm thinking of doing this with background image.

Comment: I just did it with background-image. See my EDIT. I'm actually pritty oké with that too.

Answer (score 0):

My version with background image which will do:

http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/wpdbqsjp/

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.banner .image{overflow:hidden; position:relative; background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1400x450); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; background-size: 100% auto; height:450px;}
.banner{display:block; height:450px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) { 
    .banner .image{background-size: 1400px 450px;}
}
```